# runnig inotifywait to except file's change

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, inotifywait

I am running code that allows you to execute a command if `flow.xml.gz` changes:

```
 while inotifywait -e modify,move,create,delete flow.xml.gz; do echo "test"; done
```

When I change the file nothing happens. I have only this output:

```
smadmin@sm-iotdf-mini-dev:~/nifi-1.4.0/conf$ while inotifywait -e modify,move,create,delete flow.xml.gz; do echo "test"; done
Setting up watches.
Watches established.
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about how you change the file?

Answer (score 0):

Run `inotifywait -m flow.xml.gz .` to monitor *all* events from both the file and its parent directory and see what's happening. You're only watching for 4 of the 15 types of events.

- `create` and `delete` don't do what you think. To monitor for file creation/deletion you need to watch the parent directory, not the file itself.
- Watch for `move_self` and `delete_self` if you're monitoring the file directly. Note that there's no `create_self`.